# import directory of a DLL does not work on 64bit dll

Tags: c++, dll, dependencies, portable-executable

I am trying to print the bitness and dll's that needs to be loaded for a given dll.

My code looks like this (simplified version;without error checking):

```
fh = CreateFile("my_dll_file.dll", GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
fm = CreateFileMapping(fh, NULL, PAGE_READONLY, 0, 0, NULL);
base_pointer = (char *)MapViewOfFile(fm, FILE_MAP_READ, 0, 0, 0);
pe = ImageNtHeader(base_pointer);
oh = pe->OptionalHeader;
mi = oh.Magic;
    switch (mi) {
    case IMAGE_NT_OPTIONAL_HDR64_MAGIC:
        puts("64-bit");
        break;
    case IMAGE_NT_OPTIONAL_HDR32_MAGIC:
        puts("32-bit");
        break;
    default:
        puts("no match bitness\n");
        break;
    }
rva = oh.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT].VirtualAddress;
sec = ImageRvaToSection(pe, base_pointer, rva);
sb = (char *)(base_pointer + sec->PointerToRawData);
sa = (char *)(sb - sec->VirtualAddress);
id = (IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR *)(sa + rva);
while (!IsBadReadPtr(id, sizeof(*id)) && id->Name) {
printf("\ndependency \"%s\":\n", (char *)(sa + id->Name));
id++;
}
```

However this only works with 32bit dll's. My 'rva' turns out to be 0 when tried on  64 bit dll. Bitness check in the lines above work fine though. Any pointers on what might be going wrong with 64 bit dll's?

EDIT:
I guess the problem might be that my target is x86 (and im linking against dbghelp.lib which is 32bit). Changing the target to x64 obviously gives me linker errors. However I dont have any dbghelp.lib 64 bit version to link against. Is that even available. I couldnt find it.

Comment: How are you accessing `oh.Magic` after you've done an assignation to oh? The assignation would presume that oh is a pointer (->) but you're using dot (.) notation to access it's elements - those are not compatible.  Also, why are you assigning `oh.Magic` to `mi` when you don't ever use `mi` again?

Comment: pe->OptionalHeader gives me 'oh' which is 'IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER' but not a pointer. so oh.Magic works fine for me. Also like I said, this is a simplified version of my code that works. I do use mi for other purposes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the bitness you should use pe->[FileHeader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680313.aspx).Machine:

```
switch (pe->FileHeader.Machine) {
case IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_AMD64:
    puts("64-bit");
    break;
case IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_I386:
    puts("32-bit");
    break;
default:
    puts("no match bitness\n");
    break;
}
```

Yours didn't work because there are 2 different variants of [IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680339.aspx) depending on the bitness.
So this should work for rva:

```
if (pe->FileHeader.Machine == IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_I386)
  rva = ((PIMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER32)&pe->OptionalHeader)->DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT].VirtualAddress;
else
  rva = ((PIMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER64)&pe->OptionalHeader)->DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT].VirtualAddress;
```

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who stumbles on this post in future.

As I suspected, you would need to link against 64 bit dbghelp.lib and change your target platform to x64 to work with 64 bit dlls. However this does not work for 32 bit dll's.

Looks like you need to have diff bitness programs to work on respective bitness dll.

Also dbghelp.lib is located here:
C:\Program Files\Debugging Tools for Windows (x64)\sdk\lib